# Forwarding domains to docker containers

Tags: docker, dns, routes

I want to **forward requests**(via domain name) from **public IP** to **docker containers**.
My network looks like this:
[image: Scheme of the network.]

**It should works like this:**
first.com       ->   "first" container,       172.17.0.2/16
mail.first.com  ->   "first-mail" container,  172.17.0.3/16
second.com   ->   "second" container,   172.17.0.4/16

But I have an experience only to forwarding ports. I guess I need a conditional forwarding **depended on an information of domain name** from the internet request.
Something like this for the router:

```
if(request.DomainName == "*.first.com" ||
   request.DomainName == "*.second.com"
{
    forward(request, "10.0.0.10");
}
```

And for the "Docker host" machine similarly.

But I can't find any examples for this forwarding. Am I misunderstand how it should be?

Answer (score 0):

You can use apache conf file as following settings.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass / http://172.17.0.2/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://172.17.0.2/
        ServerName first.com
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass / http://172.17.0.3/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://172.17.0.3/
        ServerName mail.first.com
</VirtualHost>
```

But this is not right way. You must read the following link

https://docs.docker.com/v17.12/datacenter/ucp/2.2/guides/user/services/use-domain-names-to-access-services/#add-a-dns-entry

Answer (score -1):

If we are talking about domain names - we are talking mostly about http\https protocols forwarding, but Docker(docker-proxy service) - is about dealing with lower levels protocols - TCP\UDP. Thats mean - we need to setup http\https proxy, that will proxing our requests to containers.

And there is a great solution - [jwilder's Nginx-Proxy](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy) - fully Automated docker-based nginx-proxy. Look at docker-compose example: After running jwilder's container you just have to add

> VIRTUAL_HOST=first.com

to first container's environment variables and remove http\https ports forwardings to host.